# Need to know about CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

In Ruby On Rails which CMS gem support the more powerful features and fully customizable functionality.

I need to create an application that have an admin that create,update and edit, delete the pages.

And wants to use customizable CSS and additional functions like i can add inside application.

For e.g Count likes of an artical on page and sharing the page on facebook.

Your help and suggestions are definably appropriate.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: You should make the CMS you want from scratch. Messing about with a gem or a engine that does not 100% fit your needs will take just as much time as building your own.

Comment: Hi, Can you please describe, what is scratch ?

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad meant that sometimes it is more useful to create your own simple CMS instead of patching an existing one to fulfill your requirements. (Thats not the case if few simple pages is all you need)

Comment: Highly surprised the SO police haven't tried to close this question for being "opinion based"

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience I can recommend [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com) which will fulfill most of your requirements. You can fully customize the CSS and it allows you to add Rails Engines to it on the one hand, but it can also be added to an existing application as a gem. You will have to do some work to get your counts and your Facebook sharing though.

I also once heard a talk from the creator of [Locomotive CMS](http://locomotivecms.com) which at first sight seems somewhat more flexible, but you will need to invest some more time to get you started. It allows transferring a running site from development to production through a companion app whereas you have to develop your content "online" with Refinery CMS.

I guess your choice will be a matter of taste. There is of course a host of other possibilities listed in the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CMS)

Answer (score 0):

To give some perspective, we recently created our own CMS from sratch

It's very simple to do - there are several tutorials online which explain the process

Basically, you need:

> **Models** - Post, User, Option
>
> **Controllers** - posts, application, users, admin: [application, posts]
>
> **Views** - application(index), posts, admin: [application(index), posts]

Here are some resources:

- http://therailworld.com/posts/12-How-to-Create-a-Blog-from-Scratch-Using-Ruby-on-Rails
- http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails/
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails?view=comments
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html